# PHP foreach multiple each and as

Tags: php, foreach

I'm trying to save code and have multiple php for each going on at the same time. Is it possible.

```
$holes9 = string(lots of information separated by,)
$stroke = string(other info separated by,)
$index = string(other info separated by,)

      $holes9 = explode(",",$holes9);
      foreach ($holes9 as $holes) {
          echo '<div class="hole"><b>'.$holes.'</b></div>
<div class="stroke"></div>
<div class="index"></div>
';
      };
```

As you can see my foreach only applies to $holes9 as $holes. How do I get the other two bits of info.

Comment: always the 3 strings contain the  same elements count?

Comment: Are the lists all same length?

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but have you tried learning the basics of PHP?

Comment: I find learning by writing is most effective thank you tomwrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$holes`, `$stroke` and `$index` have the same amount of "elements", it's enough with single `foreach`:

```
$holes9 = string(lots of information separated by,)
$stroke = string(other info separated by,)
$index = string(other info separated by,)

$holes9 = explode(",",$holes9);
$stroke = explode(",",$stroke);
$index = explode(",",$index);

foreach ($holes9 as $id => $holes) {
    echo '
        <div class="hole"><b>'.$holes9[$id].'</b></div>
        <div class="stroke">'.$stroke[$id].'</div>
        <div class="index">'.$index[$id].'</div>
    ';
};
```

Comment: +1 For providing a working solution AND noting about the different length problem.

Answer (score 2):

If the strings are of the same separation length (i.e. they will have the same number of commas `,`), then you can do it like this:

```
$holes9 = 'lots, of information, separated, by a, comma';
$stroke = 'other, info, separated, by, a comma';
$index = 'another, info, string, separated by, a comma';

$holes9 = explode(',',$holes9);
$strokes = explode(',', $strokes);
$index = explode(',', $index);

foreach ($holes9 as $id => $holes) {
    echo '<div class="hole"><b>'.$holes.'</b></div>'.
         '<div class="stroke">'.$strokes[$id].'</div>'.
         '<div class="index">'.$index[$id].'</div>';
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$holes9 = explode(",",$holes9);
$stroke = explode(",",$stroke); // explode these as well
$index = explode(",",$index);

foreach ($holes9 as $n => $holes) // take advantage of referencing the numeric key
{
  echo '<div class="hole"><b>'.$holes.'</b></div>';
  echo '<div class="stroke">'.$stroke[$n].'</div>';
  echo '<div class="index">'.$index[$n].'</div>';
}
```

Since `explode()` will generate numeric keys, make use of the foreach's ability to grab a key and a value. The first echo uses the value, then re-use the key (in this case `$n`) to reference the same element indexes in the other two arrays (`$stroke` and `$index`, assuming these will have the same number of elements.)

Answer (score 0):

If the length of all the lists is the same you can do this:

```
$holes9 = string(lots of information separated by,)
$stroke = string(other info separated by,)
$index = string(other info separated by,)

      $holes9 = explode(",",$holes9);
      foreach ($holes9 as $key => $holes) {
          echo '<div class="hole"><b>'.$holes.'</b></div>
<div class="stroke">'.$stroke[$key].'</div>
<div class="index">'.$index[$key].'</div>
';
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your 3 strings contain the same number of elements you can use for instead of foreach like that :

```
$holes9 = explode(",",$holes9);
$stroke = explode(",",$stroke);
$index = explode(",",$index);

for($i =0; $i < ;$i++){

echo '<div class="hole"><b>'.$holes9[$i].'</b></div>
<div class="stroke">'.$stroke[$i].'</div>
<div class="index">'.$index[$i].'</div>';
}
```